# Multiple X values, needing two scatter plot lines

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2010, scatter-plot

I'm having a hard time using a line and/or scatter chart. I'm attempting to have a Y axis of 0-5 for example with two separate data series for X values.

Eg:  Say Y is days of the week. On X it has 0-100.

I'd like two lines (data series). One representing sodas drank that would have an appropriate data point for each X/Y. Then another colored line for how many bottled waters or something. Both would fit within the X and Y axes minima and maxima.
My attempt (the red line I drew in the upper chart is my basic goal):

[image: The red line I drew in the upper chart is my basic goal]

I can get one to work at a time:

[image: I can get one to work at a time]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the desired chart will appear in response to little more than a single click but I found not such simple way for what I believe to be your requirement. You got one to work at a time so I suggest taking it from there.

In that scatter plot, bring up the Select Data Source window and click Add. Select Range for Series X values: as A2:A7 and for Series Y values: as C2:C7.

[image: SO20976031 example]

I think the chart on the left is your starting point and (hope) the chart on the right is your desired result.

BTW I’m using Excel 2007.

Comment: Sometimes you must add each series one at a time. In Excel 2013, it is now sometimes possible to create an XY chart that uses alternating columns as the X and Y data for successive series (for example, series 1 X data in column A and Y data in column B, Series 2 X in column C and Y in column D...).